# How to check whether object Containing object collection

Tags: java, object

In Java i want to find whether object is a object collection??

```
String [] abc=new String[]{"Joe","John"};
Object ob=abc;
```

I want to check varaible ob holds object collection??How can i do this??

Comment: Adrian Shum is right,abc is not a collection, but an Array. Nice overview: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/File:Java_collection_implementation.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check with `instanceof` operator.

> The instanceof operator compares an object to a specified type. You can use it to test if an object is an instance of a class, an instance of a subclass, or an instance of a class that >implements a particular interface.
>   [reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html)

```
String [] abc=new String[]{"Joe","John"};
Object ob=abc;
...
if(ob instanceof String[]){
   String[] str = (String[])ob;
}else{...}
```

Comment: How to convert "ob" to String collection(ie same that we assigned)

Answer (score 2):

You can use Java reflections, like this:

```
Class<?> clazz = ob.getClass();
boolean isArray = clazz.isArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

From your example, what you need to check is more precisely, Object Array instead of collection.

You can try something like

```
String [] abc=new String[]{"Joe","John"}; 
Object ob=abc;
if (ob instanceof Object[]) {
  // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First check is it an array with:

```
boolean isArray = ob.getClass().isArray();
```

or

```
if (ob instanceof Object[]) {

  // ...

}
```

If not check is it an collection by checking with instanceof and `java.util.Collection` interface:

```
if (ob instanceof Collection) {

  // ...

}
```